# How to post a json and get a file stream in return in Framework 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I wrote a webservice (web api 2) and tested it successfully with the http Client. One of the Services took a json string and validated it, and then returned an appropriate download stream.

Now though I found out that I Need to write a 3.5 Framework Client for handling the whole Transfer (posting the json data and then getting the file).

As example for getting a text with web Client:

```
private string GetTextFromUrl(string url, JObject jsonObject)
{
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");

    return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(webClient.UploadData(url, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonObject.ToString())));
}
```

Now though I'm a bit at a loss. From what I see with the webclient only OpenRead and DownloadFile return streams while everything else Returns a Byte Array.

Both though use only the URL and don't do any Posts (like upload data does). So I'm wondering there: Is there any possibility to post json data to a URL and receive a stream in Response with Framework 3.5? (not necessarily limited to webclient).

Edit:
To clarify as it was asked: The Client Posts a json string to the Server and receives a stream in Response. That is what I try to achieve (Client side wise).

Comment: Did you try to use `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` nuget package?

Comment: @saadi nope didn't try that so far (I'm a bit at a loss at Framework 3.5 and my googlefu didn't bring up much aside from the webclient above). reading through it nwo

Comment: Right-click on your project, select manage nuget package and search for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client

Comment: @saadi isn't that the WebClient I mentioned above? (took a long look but don't see any difference)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options but that is not really the problem. I think you are missing out on [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

**Using WebClient**
Post using webclient in .NET 3.5 is done as below by specifying headers and the "POST" method.

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");//set content-type header here
string response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(client.UploadData("http://localhost:1111/Service.svc/SignIn", "POST", Encoding.Default.GetBytes("{\"Data\": \"JSON DATA HERE\"}")));
```

Usually when you do the above, you should get a response from the upload method that you can assign to a variable 'response' and then use JSON.NET.

Please see this [link](http://www.thepicketts.org/2012/11/how-to-access-webapi-from-a-net-3-5-client-in-c/) here as well. He doesn't specify the method but uses JSON.NET and seems to work for him.

**Using WebRequest**
You could also try WebRequest. Please see this link for [webrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class) example

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that method to UPload data and files. But when downloading I would get a Byte[] Response from that method. Could I use that to download a filestream? (thus using uplaoddata to download a filestream)

Comment: Based on the 1st paragraph of your initial post, I assumed that this is the service you want to interact with in your client, the service should receive a json post request, process the data & spit out data as a response (the "filestream") to the client. Right?

In your client, you should be able to 1) Serialize the data to json 2) Post this data along with the headers outlined in my comment 3) receive a response and then process it.

Response from service after the post should contain your filestream. You should not have to download it again.

Do you have some code that we can see?

Comment: not exactly.  the Client (who uses the webclient)  Posts a json string to the webservice and receives a stream in Response.